# Why should we have $\sin^2(x) = \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$ knowing that $\sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos^2(x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

> Why should we have $\sin^2(x) = \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$ knowing that $\sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos^2(x)$?

Logically, can you not subtract $\cos^2(x)$ to the other side from this Pythagorean identity $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1?$

When I look up trig identities, however, it says $\sin^2(x) = \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$.

Why is this?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Please use LaTeX.

Comment: @A.Molendijk or you know MathJax

Comment: The second formula is the double angle formula.

Comment: Both formulas are true, they don't contradict themselves.

Comment: Your proposed identity $\sin^2 x = 1-\cos^2 x$ is correct. And so is the one you "looked up", tha $\sin^2 x = \dfrac{1-\cos(2x)} 2. \qquad $

Comment: @A.Molendijk : What is used here is not LaTeX, but MathJax. Anyone who masters MathJax and thinks it's LaTeX will suffer an unpleasant shock when they encounter actual LaTeX and find out they don't know it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks! Is it the other way around as well? I dont think so right?

Comment: @A.Molendijk : Nearly all of what can be done with mathematical notation in LaTeX, or at least the simplest things, which are most of what is done, works the same way in MathJax. The big difference is that LaTeX handles many more things than just mathematical notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $\cos^{2}(x):=(\cos(x))^{2}$ is not the same thing as $\cos(2x)$. It is indeed true that $\sin^{2}(x)=1-\cos^{2}(x)$ and that $\sin^{2}(x)=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

Both formulas are true, however, both are useful in different contexts (applications).

- You use $\sin^2(x) = \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$ for integrating $\sin^2(x)$.
- You use $\sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos^2(x)$, for example, when solving $\sin^2(x) = 2\cos(x)$.

Note that it is just in some way more "natural" to write $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x)=1$, because this gives both $\sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos^2(x)$ and $\cos^2(x) = 1 - \sin^2(x)$ in one "natural looking" formula.

Answer (score 2):

From the angle addition formula, we have

$$\begin{align}
\cos(2x)&=\cos(x+x)\\\\
&=\cos(x)\cos(x)-\sin(x)\sin(x)\\\\
&=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)\\\\
&=\left(1-\sin^2(x)\right)-\sin^2(x)\\\\
&=1-2\sin^2(x)\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Solving $(1)$ for $\sin^2(x)$ yields

$$\sin^2(x)=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$$

as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Let's address two things, the question in the post and the confusion others have pointed out.

### Part 1: Proof

Here's a proof that $\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)=1$, from which you can show that $\sin^2(\theta)=1-\cos^2(\theta)$. It requires a bit of set up using the Euler identity and that $i=\sqrt{-1}$.  If you are not familiar with complex numbers, find yourself a video on YouTube, you'll get the hang of them in next to no time.

$$e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\tag{1}$$
$$e^{-i\theta}=\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta)\tag{2}$$
Now, add (1) and (2).
$$e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta)=2\cos(\theta)\tag{3}$$

Subtract (2) from (1)
$$e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)-\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)=2i\sin(\theta)\tag{4}$$
From (3) and (4) we get (5) and (6)
$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}\tag{5}$$
$$\sin(\theta)=\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}\tag{6}$$

now, add the squares of (5) and (6)
$$\cos^2(\theta)=\frac{e^{2i\theta}+2e^{i\theta-i\theta}+e^{-2i\theta}}{4}=\frac{e^{2i\theta}+2+e^{-2i\theta}}{4}\tag{7}$$
$$\sin^2(\theta)=\frac{e^{2i\theta}-2e^{i\theta-i\theta}+e^{-2i\theta}}{-4}=\frac{e^{2i\theta}-2+e^{-2i\theta}}{-4}\tag{8}$$

$$\cos^2(\theta)+sin^2(\theta)=\frac{e^{2i\theta}+2+e^{-2i\theta}}{4}+\frac{e^{2i\theta}-2+e^{-2i\theta}}{-4}=\frac{e^{2i\theta}+2+e^{-2i\theta}-e^{2i\theta}+2-e^{-2i\theta}}{4}\tag{9}$$

$$\cos^2(\theta)+sin^2(\theta)=\frac{e^{2i\theta}+2+e^{-2i\theta}-e^{2i\theta}+2-e^{-2i\theta}}{4}=\frac{4}{4}=1\tag{10}$$

### Part 2: Addressing the confusion of $\cos(2x)$ and $\cos^2(x)$

$$\cos(2\theta)=\frac{e^{2i\theta}+e^{-2i\theta}}{2}= \frac{\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^2+\left(e^{-i\theta}\right)^2}{2} = \frac{(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^2+(\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta))^2}{2}\tag{11}$$
Processing this result further, we obtain

$$\cos(2\theta)=\frac{\cos^2(\theta)+2i\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) -2i\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta) }{2}=\frac{2\cos^2(\theta)-2\sin^2(\theta)}{2}$$
Therefore
$$\cos(2\theta)=\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(2\theta)\tag{12}$$.

Ok, you stated that $$\sin^2(x)=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}\tag{13}$$
well, if you substitute the result from (12) into (13), you find that

$$\sin^2(\theta)=\frac{1-\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(2\theta)}{2}\tag{14}$$
Rearrange this (multiply both sides by 2 and then subtract the $sin^2(\theta)$ from the right side to the left) to get 
$$\sin^2(\theta)=1-\cos^2(\theta)\tag{15}$$